# Filtering Nothing from a List with foldr/foldl

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm trying to implement catMaybes with List folding but have no clue how i should start.

My general idea is to use foldl and use a case to filter for Nothing and Just. After that the same function has to concat the found parts together my code this far looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
catMaybes xs = foldl((++) \case Nothing -> []; Just y -> y) [] xs
```

I'm getting alot of errors when compiling...
I think i need a push in the right direction to solve this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This tries to apply `(++)` to the non-list `\case ...`, which makes little sense. I'd suggest to try `foldr (\x rest -> case x of ...) []`.

Comment: `\case Nothing -> []; Just y -> [y]` can also be spelled `toList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just y -> y
```

If this needs to unify with `[]` then you should have said `[Maybe [a]]` in the function type signature.  That or perhaps you meant `Just y -> [y]`.

```
(++) \case Nothing -> []; Just y -> y
```

That's just syntacticly nonsense.  I think you want 1. function composition 2. partial application of the first argument:

```
\b -> (b ++) . \case Nothing -> []; Just y -> y
```